# jquery dialog not opening constanly in frames on window blur event

Tags: jquery, frame, frameset

I need to trigger a jquery dialog box on window blur event. But it is not throwing the dialog due the presence of frameset with multiple frames in the page. So I created an empty div in one of the frame and appended the generated dialog with it. Now it is throwing the dialog only once. But I need it to throw every time the blur event occurs with window.

Thanks in advance.

Browser: Chrome, Firefox and IE9.

Jquery lib included: jquery-1.3.2.js, jquery-ui-1.7.2.js, jQuery-ui-1.7.2.css

More info:

I have created this empty div in 2nd frame

```
<div id='testpop'></div>
```

and used this following code in common js file to trigger the blur event

```
$(window).blur(function() {
    ConfirmBox();
});

function ConfirmBox() {
    var timer;
    $('<div id="confirm" style="display: none"><p>Are you sure?</p></div>').dialog({
        closeOnEscape: false,
        resizable: false,
        position: top,
        width: 500,
        modal: true,

        open: function(event, ui) {
            timer = setTimeout(function() { alert("Logout"); }, 30000); 
        },
        buttons:
                                {
                                    "Logout": function() {
                                        alert("Logout");

                                    },
                                    "Resume": function() {
                                        $(this).dialog("close");
                                        clearTimeout(timer);
                                    }
                                }
    });
    if ($(window.frames[1].document)) {
        $('#testpop', window.frames[1].document).html($('#confirm').parent());
        $('#testpop', window.frames[1].document).show();
    }
}
```

Based on this code it is throwing the dialog box once in the page for very first blur event. Next time the blur event is not triggering  properly.

Please let me know if I have missed anything in the code.

Comment: Would help to know the browser and version info

Comment: It is always helpful to share the code that is not working for you. [ask]

Comment: @phillip I have added the code for you. Pls share your ideas.Thanks.